# How to break an infinite loop using previewMouseUp?

Tags: c#, wpf

Currently, I start looping upon `PreviewMouseDown` and I was thinking to break the loop using `PreviewMouseUp` but apparently failed. Below is the way I did it.

```
public bool stopFlag = true;
public int abc = 0;
private void TestingDown(){
    while(stopFlag)
    {
       abc++;
    }
}

private void TestingUp()
{
    stopFlag = false;
    Message.show(abc);
}
```

Actually my idea is to create sort of button holding effect, something like smartphone, hold a button for 3 seconds and do something. But there isnt any `onHold` event for button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start the `Timer` in `PreviewMouseDown` and check elapsed time in `PreviewMouseUp`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case your loop runs in the same thread as the whole UI. But actually what you need is to calculate the time between MouseDown and MouseUp events.

```
    DateTime holdStartTime;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        PreviewMouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(MainWindow_PreviewMouseDown);
        PreviewMouseUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(MainWindow_PreviewMouseUp);
    }

    void MainWindow_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        holdStartTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    void MainWindow_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((DateTime.Now - holdStartTime).TotalMilliseconds < 1000)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do something");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do something else");
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need backgroud thread for this as UI thread is busy in this loop.
You can refer below link for more info.
[Background Worker]

Comment: Can I have your link? Thanks

Comment: i dont whats gone wrong with above link. here it is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx